# How to flatMap a Flux with a Mono?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am building a service that call two REST resources. The first call retrieve a list of items and the second get the details of each item in the list.

```
Flux<Result> search(query) {
    return client.post().uri("/search")
       .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(query))
       .retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(SearchResults.class)
       .flatMapIterable(r -> r.getResults())
       .flatMap(this::detail);
}

Mono<Detail> detail(result) {
    return client.get().uri("/detail/{id}", result.id)
        .retrieve()
        .doOnNext(System.out::println))
        .bodyToMono(Detail.class);
}
```

I can see that the `GET /detail/{id}` request is sent, but the `doOnNext` in the `this::detail` block is never called from my test:

```
StepVerifier.create(target.search(query))
    .assertNext(d -> {
        assertThat(d.getField()).isEqualTo("detailed");
    })
    .verifyComplete();
```

And this test fail with :

> java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "assertNext" failed (expected: onNext(); actual: onComplete())

I am a bit stuck at this stage, the Reactor documentation use `flatMap` for this kind of case and it looks like the sub request (for details) is sent. While looking at Wirmock, I see that he is able to return a response but then I have nothing more.

Does anyone has an idea of what goes wrong ?

Comment: Can you call subsribe as the last statement in the detail function?

Comment: Yes. I can do `client.get().uri("/detail/{id}")....subscribe()` but this returns a `Disposable` and it is the same as in the `doOnNext` , the block is never executed.

Comment: It looks like this is due to the `bodyToMono` that is not able to unmarshal the Xml response body. But I have no errors on the stream nor anywhere in the logs

Comment: .retrieve() will result in Mono.error if the Http Response is not 200, in which case doOnNext will not be called.
You can try to use .retrieve() instead, then you can do .map(resp -> {System.out.println(resp.statusCode()); return resp}

Comment: And to debug it further you can get the response as a string, then log it and then decode it into JSON object manually using Jackson. Just use 
.bodyToMono(String.class).map(s -> {System.out.println(s); 
// here use Jackson to decode and return result object
}

Comment: Have you tested your APIs separately with WebTestClient.

Comment: @Dimitri I already map the status via `onStatus` and I get no errors. Actually I am returning the body as string and it is as expected. I am using a cutsom `HttpMessageReader` that just delegate to a `javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` and it goes better (I got an object). I am suspecting the defaults `HttpMessageReader` to fail on the Xml that I receive.